# Meaning of "radio" in a a Radio Interface Layer (RIL) context

Tags: ril

It may be a stupid question. I'm confused.
Regarding the radio on a Radio Interface Layer (RIL) context. 
By "radio", one means the GSM radio or the wi-fi radio?

Answer (score 1):

The Android Open Source Project provides a Radio Interface Layer (RIL) between Android telephony services (android.telephony) and the radio hardware.

It consists of a stack of two components: a RIL Daemon and a Vendor RIL. The RIL Daemon talks to the telephony services and dispatches "solicited commands" to the Vendor RIL. The Vendor RIL is specific to a particular radio implementation, and dispatches "unsolicited commands" up to the RIL Daemon

So from this point of view it points to GSM